# Problem with Deserializing data from WebApi in NSwag generated code

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, blazor, nswag

I have an API method that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("top/{max}", Name = "GetTopLocations")]
public ActionResult<List<LocationDto>> GetTop(int max)
{
    return _locationService.Get();
}
```

I have then generated client code class with NSwag via Swagger. I call this method in my Blazor WebAssembly code like this:

```
Locations = await MyProject.Client.GetTopLocationsAsync(10);
```

However, this generates an exception:

﻿

```
Error: 0 : Could not deserialize the response body stream as System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[MyProject.LocationDto, MyProject.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
```

But if I call this method in my browser like this: http://localhost:50464/api/Locations/top/10
and then take that JSON string and test to Deserialize it like this:

```
string jsonStringCopiedFromBrowser = "...";
var thisWorks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<LocationDto>>(jsonStringCopiedFromBrowser);
```

I cannot understand why it works when I deserialize it like in the last code but not from NSwag? Any tips on what I am doing wrong? I have not modified the NSwag generated code at all, its taken directly from the generated output.

Comment: I have problems with autogenerated NSwag code too. try changing JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<LocationDto> to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LocationDto>>

Comment: Does the first call return an error perhaps? Use Fiddler or another debugging proxy to see what's actually returned by the server. What does the HTTP response actually look like? And what's the actual *full exception text*?

Answer (score 0):

NSwag Studio does not help with this kind of operation.
so you need to create a List mannunally.
I try and its work
here is the code below

```
 public class Response<T>
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ValidatonError { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public IList<T> DataEnum { get; set; }

} 

    public async Task<Response<EmployeeDetailDTO>> GetEmployee(int ID)
    {
        Response<EmployeeDetailDTO> response;
        try
        {
           
            var data = await client.EmployeeAllAsync(ID);
            response = new Response<EmployeeDetailDTO>
            {
                DataEnum = data.ToList(),
                Success = true
            };
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            response = ConvertApiException<EmployeeDTO>(e);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Now extract the result on your Client Page

```
 @foreach(var model in rl.ToArray())
         {
          <td>@model.Complaintname</td>
         }
```

after a couple of hours, I use this method for solving the problem. NSwag Studio work if you send a single Record.